Need Process Explorer to start minimized at startup
I need Process Explorer to start minimized at startup. I thought it had an option but I cannot find it.  I have Process Explorer set to start with windows up I want it to start minimized.  Any ideas? Windows 11

To make any application start minimized, make a desktop shortcut to it, then, in the Properties dialog for the shortcut (.lnk file), set Run to Minimized.

If you want to run that app automatically at logon, put the shortcut in the user's Startup folder (e.g.,
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\).
Putting it in C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp should also work.
